# Google app engine entities are not being created

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I am developing an android application using google endpoints and google app engine. My backend does not seem to actually be doing anything. It appears as if nothing is being saved to the datastore and therefore nothing can be retrieved from it.

Here are some of the **Api methods** I have written in endpoints that are not working:

```
private static String getUserId(User user) {
        String userId = user.getUserId();
        if (userId == null) {
            AppEngineUser appEngineUser = new AppEngineUser(user);
            ofy().save().entity(appEngineUser).now();
            // Begin new session for not using session cache.
            Objectify objectify = ofy().factory().begin();
            AppEngineUser savedUser = objectify.load().key(appEngineUser.getKey()).now();
            userId = savedUser.getUser().getUserId();
        }
        return userId;
    }

    @ApiMethod(name = "saveProfile", path = "profile", httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.POST)
    public Profile saveProfile(final User user, final ProfileForm profileForm) throws UnauthorizedException {
        if(user == null) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException("Authorization required.");
        }

        String firstName = profileForm.getFirstName();
        String surname = profileForm.getLastName();
        String userEmail = user.getEmail();
        int year = profileForm.getYear();
        int month = profileForm.getMonth();
        int day = profileForm.getDay();

        Profile profile = ofy().load().key(Key.create(Profile.class, getUserId(user))).now();

        if (profile == null) {
            // the user does not have a profile and is creating one for the first time
            profile = new Profile(getUserId(user), firstName, surname, userEmail, year, month, day);
        } else {
            profile.update(firstName, surname, userEmail, year, month, day);
        }
        ofy().save().entity(profile).now();
        return profile;
    }

    @ApiMethod(name = "getProfile", path = "profile", httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.GET)
    public Profile getProfile(User user) throws UnauthorizedException {
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException("Authentication required.");
        }
        return ofy().load().key(Key.create(Profile.class, getUserId(user))).now();
    }
}
```

The profile class has the `@Entity` annotation and is registered with objectify in a static block like so:

```
static {
        factory().register(AppEngineUser.class);
        factory().register(Profile.class);
}
```

The userId is generated by GAE through

```
com.google.appengine.api.users.User
```

and the userId property is a String with the `@Index` annotation.

I am also confused by the api explorer and how it is responding to these methods. Whenever I call the saveProfile api method, a profile object is returned with a `userId` of `0` and an email of `"example@example.com"` although I believe this is the default email when running on localhost.

I am also running api explorer over HTTP,Google says this "can cause problems." Is this the reason why nothing is working. I have had to load unsafe scripts just for me to use my api, but maybe it does not work as it is hosted over HTTP instead of HTTPS.

Is this entire problem of not being able to fully test my methods due to a fundamental flaw in my understanding of GAE or is due to me running on localhost. If it is the latter perhaps I should deploy to Appspot and things may run smoother.

If there is anything extra you need to help, please just ask.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your logs in the developers console. It records all API methods that you execute and will show if any have any errors.

Since you are getting example@example.com as the email of the User this leads me to believe the User is not being injected by GAE. This is probably because you are doing something wrong client side (e.g. in Android). Make sure your Android app correctly asks to log a user in with Google and pass those credentials to your builder object in Android.

If you are executing your API method via the api explorer, you need to be logged in as a google user first for that User object to be populated in your method (I think you already know that).

In short, check your logs and your client code.